# Dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation_reader"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

So I have a Symfony 6.2 API, PHP 8.2 codebase.

While trying to run composer install/update the following error is displaying and I'm wondering how to clear it:

```
In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 83:
The service "doctrine.orm.default_annotation_metadata_driver" has a dependency 
on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.metadata.annotation_reader".
```

If I comment out the mappings section in doctrine.yaml file (below) composer runs successfully, however all POST requests to the api will then result in the following error:

```
Could not find the entity manager for class App\Entity\Token.
Check your Doctrine configuration to make sure it is configured 
to load this entity’s metadata. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Scratching my head here to understand how to resolve it. I've a feeling it may be doctrine.yaml related but I could be miles off the mark.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        ...
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
        ...
    },
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
```

Comment: How did you create your app?  A simple `symfony new --webapp` or some other more involved approach? Sort of sounds like you are missing a doctrine dependency.

Comment: With annotations being deprecated ideally we should be removing this component.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are missing the `doctrine/annotations`dependency. Try to add in your `composer.json` file:

```
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
```

Then run `composer update`. Or just run:

```
composer require doctrine/annotations
```

Comment: that alone doesn't help, and `composer require doctrine/annotations` is much better.

Answer (score 21):

In symfony `6.4` and up, if you get `non-existent service "annotation_reader".` errors,

you may need to remove `annotations: false` from `config/packages/framework.yaml`.

Comment: Thank you ! Save me from days of debugging hell.

Comment: Thnx! Made me the day! Just upgraded from 6.3 to 6.4 and it broke. It should not break.

Comment: Nevertheless I changed my mind. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78175454/1315009

Answer (score 8):

It will not be the exact answer to your question, but my advice is to move PHP 8.1 attributes instead of doctrine annotations.

Trying to install `doctrine/annotations`, which will require version [2.0](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/annotations#2.0.0) gave me conflicts with other tools that required version 1.x.

Set your Symfony DoctrinBundle [mapping type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#type) to `attribute`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

    form:
        ...
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: attribute
```

More info about the attribute settings can be found here:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/attributes-reference.html

Comment: Did you need to do anything else? This alone doesn't resolve the dependency.

Comment: Ah found it, `doctrine.orm.auto_mapping` needs to be `false` too.

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP 8 attributes for routing annotations instead of use deprecated `doctrine/annotations` package as noted in their deprecation notice : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/2.0/index.html#deprecation-notice

```
    PHP 8 introduced attributes, which are a native replacement for annotations. 
    As such, this library is considered feature complete, 
    and should receive exclusively bugfixes and security fixes.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected the error by adding:

```
composer require doctrine/annotations
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while upgrading symfony 5.4.* to 6.4.

In my case, it was caused by using annotations instead of attributes in my Entities.

I fixed it by changing my annotations to attributes, it's quite easy, just takes some manual work.

In my doctrine.yaml I changed the entity mapping type: `type: annotation` to `type: attribute`.

After that you have to edit your Entities:

From:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class User implements UserInterface
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private int $id;
}
```

To:

```
#[ORM\Table(name: "users")]
#[ORM\Entity]

class User implements UserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Column(name: "id", type: "integer", nullable: false)]
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "IDENTITY")]
    private int $id;
}
```

Imports stays the same:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Afterwards you can remove `doctrine/annotations` from your project by removing it from package.json or running `composer remove doctrine/annotations`

Answer (score -2):

In my case the error appeared when upgrading from symfony 6.3 to 6.4.

I initially followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77596031/1315009 by @simon-epskamp but after that, I saw that the last time I did `composer recipes:update symfony/framework-bundle` precisely the recipe set `annotations: false`, so I did not feel well about removing that line.

I finally saw that the one invoking the annotations was the `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` so I did this:

```
composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

After that, the error vanished.

Comment: This dependency is not installed per default

Comment: It was in the past, so if you have some old project and you are upgrading and upgrading, at some point you encounter this situation.